# how does to use Google Analytics without to worry about GDPR or cookies?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, gdprconsentform

I would like to use google analytics only for grab technical informations of my visitors, for example browser used, resolution of the display, languages, number of users connected at time, urls visited etc.

I don't want to worry my users about gdpr, cookies and other legal stuffs, because i don't want to track them, i need only technical informations.

[In this article](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2020/06/google-analytics-cookieless-tracking-without-gdpr-consent/) i read i can deactivate the use of cookies so, even every visits will be unique, i will don't need to ask for cookies acceptance anymore.

this can be sufficient to avoid asking to my visitors about permission relateed to cookies , tracking or gdpr?

thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it might be appropriate to ask on [law.se].

Answer (score 1):

The Google Analytics cookie is first party. You have to use IP Anonymization (or IP masking) in Analytics so your cookie can be assimilated to technical cookies.

ATTENTION: not all privacy guarantors agree with this statement.

If you use Google Analytics 4 the IP anonymization is already automatic.